# Extracting Gurobi Solution Index

Tags: python, indexing, gurobi

I have a bunch of gurobi variables
y[0],y[1],...,y[n]
x[0],x[1],...,x[m].
I would like to be able to figure out the indices of the optimal y's that are not zero.  In other words, if the optimal solution is y[0]=0, y[1]=5, y[2]=0, y[3]=1, I would like to return [1,3].  So far, I have

```
F = []
for v in model.getVars():
   if v.varName[0]=='y' and v.x>0:
     F.append[v.varName]
```

This, in the above example, would give me ['y[1]', 'y[3]'].  Since this output is a string, I'm not sure how I can get the 1 and 3 out of it.  Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following which works:

```
Index_List = []
for v in m.getVars():
       if v.varName[0] == 'y' and v.x>0:

           Index = int(v.varName[2]) 

           for j in range(3,3+100)):
               BOOL = False 
               try:
                   IndexNEW =int(v.varName[j])
                   Index = 10*Index+IndexNEW
                   BOOL = True
               except ValueError:
                   ()
               if not BOOL:
                   break
       Index_List.append(Index)
```

The resulting Index_List is as desired.  There must be a better way though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
from gurobipy import *
m = Model()
```

If you create a gurobi tupledict for your variables with

```
x = m.addVars(nx, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="x")
y = m.addVars(ny, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="y")
# ...your constraints and objective here..
```

then you can directly call the attributes for your variables (in your case the `.X` attribute for the variable value in the current solution). Using a list comprehension it could be done with:

```
m.optimize()
if m.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    indices = [i for i in range(ny) if y[i].X > 0]
```

where `nx` and `ny` are the number of your variables.